# Sublime Text 2 long web fetch time

Tags: osx-lion, macbook-pro, sublime-text-2

Always when Sublime Text 2 connects to the web, e.g. for listing and fetching packages with Package Control, it takes a huge amount of time to load. I even had to disable the LiveReload Package because always on startup it loads a .js file from the web, which leads to app startup times of nearly 30 seconds. That's very annoying.

It seems as a similar problem appears when I'm sending an email from Mail.app, which takes about 30 seconds until it starts to upload. When I'm in another network that delay does not take place. I didn't test Sublime Text 2 in another network, so I can't tell if this is related.

I have a 13" MacBook Pro (2009), that is connected to the web through a netopia (3356N-VGx) router.

My internet connection is about 5000 kbit/s, which should be fast enough. I think that something is blocking the connection, but I don't what it could be or how I could find out.

Does anyone know where I'd have to start looking?